# Why github username and commit name is not the same?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I have uploaded my project on github and on the website I have different username and commit name:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFsif.png)

For this post I have changed it to "NAME 1" and "NAME 2" .

Why aren't they same? I think I have changed it in the past ( because NAME 2 is familiar for me: it is my last name )and now I don't know where have I changed it.
I want to change it to NAME 1 (to my github username).

I tried to change Git user.email and user.name but these have no affect to NAME 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check your user name and user email in your local git config:

```
$ git config --list
```

If it's different then you can change it for the next commits:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"  
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

The other way, you can use a special file in your repo to change a user name and email to something else

Create a file named `.mailmap`

And add this line:

`Name 1 <name1@email.com> Name 2 <name2@email.com>`

Comment: Thank you. Thats why I have first , I have changed user.name.

Comment: The  author of commits that pushed in the remote repo can't change easily and it's very risky. You may lost your commits refs by doing this. The safest way is to use .mailmap but it's not affects on remote history. Just will change it for you in local history

Comment: Thank you. I did not changed in the past mailmap, and yet my commit name is my lastname there. So I don't know where I have changed it to it.

Comment: Check this: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmailmap for more information

Comment: Now I know. I have changed again my name and email with git config --global user.name and git config --global user.email. With this method I have changed NAME 2 (so I have replaced my lastname) to a new one. You mentioned something is risky, but i did not undestood it very well. Do you mean it is recommended to set git config --global user.email and git config --global user.name TO my github email and username?? Thank you

Comment: No, I didn't explain the risky way :). It is a forbidden hack that will change your commit ref but also your commit author to current user.  Forget about it. But for your curiosity you can read this article: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email

Comment: Thank you. Is it recommend to set my user.name and user.email to the same as Github email and name? In the past as i told these values were different. I mean I had different Github name and different git config user.name . Is it recommend to set email and name to Github-Email and Github-Name ?
I ask this because I think user.email is public the same way as user.name is public. I don't want my e-mail to be public thats why I have set user.name and user.email something else.

Comment: They should be the same

Comment: Thank you. For user.name I have set my github username, but for my user.email i have set random , because i think it is public in logs as the user.name and i don't want my e-mail to be public on github